# Io.popen stucks and cmd gets not closed

Tags: ruby

I call the method `send_csr1` from the method `send_crs` with this line of code:

```
send_csr1(pipe.read,@username,@password)
```

The problem is that normally the next line of code would be executed:

```
pipe.close_write
```

But somehow it wont what results in that the cmd is never closed. When i close it manually i get the error:

```
  in `read': Interrupt
    from stack.rb:49:in `block in send_csr'
    from stack.rb:45:in `popen'
    from stack.rb:45:in `send_csr'
    from stack.rb:88:in `block in <main>'
    from stack.rb:87:in `each'
    from stack.rb:87:in `<main>'
```

My question is what do i have to change in my code, that ruby surley closes the cmd?

My full code:

```
def send_csr
 IO.popen('cmd', 'r+') do |pipe|
 pipe.puts('cd C:/OpenSSL/bin')
 pipe.puts('openssl.exe')
 pipe.puts("req  -config c:/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf -in  #{@csr}")
 send_csr1(pipe.read,@username,@password)   
 pipe.close_write
end
end

def send_csr1(text,user,password)
 @conn.basic_auth(user,password)
 @res = @conn.get do |request|  
 request.url "csr"
 request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
 request.body = "#{text}"
end
end
```

Comment: probably pipe.read is blocking waiting for it to read "all the input" try using recv instead or some other method like gets [?]

Comment: There is no mehod recv but basically its a good idea!